Use the Copy Database Wizard
We have:

The main server (MSX) with Windows Server 2022 Standard OS and Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Standard SBUD.
The target server (TSX) with Windows Server 2019 Standard OS and Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Developer SBUD.

With great difficulty I created a multi-server environment, but that's not the main thing.
I want to use the Copy Database Wizard to copy the database from the main server to the target one. I've read the official manual 100 times, but nothing works, and some points marked as mandatory to perform are not necessary at all, it works without it.
But following all the rules, copying always ends with the same error:

InnerException: the user does not have permission to modify the "Test_DB" database, or this database does not exist or is in a state that does not allow access checking.

I tried to run SQL Server Agent under different accounts, both local admin and domain admin.
I also linked different accounts to the DB.
In general, I tried a bunch of options, but the result was the same error.
If anyone has used this method and can tell me which way to dig, please tell me!
Using the official documentation, I expected to copy the database from one server to another. But I didn't get it.

Вопрос решён, всем спасибо за помощь
